# How do I call a class contained in a folder in C#/Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

[image]
[image]

This is probably a very stupid question;

I've just been attempting to make my first Universal App in Visual Studio. Anyway, I'm attempting to make a class file which can be called from both the Phone and Store app, however, VS keeps storing this .cs file in a folder.

How can I call the class when it's in a folder?

Normally I'd just do something like:

`ClassName class1 = new ClassName()`

but this won't work as I don't know how to put the folder in their, if you know what I mean; I've tried

`FolderName.ClassName() class1 = new FolderName.ClassName()` 
but to no avail.

Can someone tell me how to reference a class contained in a folder?

Thanks.

Edit: I've added an image. I'm trying to access a method contained in Print.cs in MainPage.xaml.cs

**ANSWER: Put classes that I intend to share in the "UniApp1.Shared" folder (Duh!) :/**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added your class into *solution items*. Solution items are not compiled into your project's output. Simply move the class into your project (a simple drag-n-drop should do) and it will work fine.

Comment: I've moved it into the Windows Phone project, but how do I call the code from Windows Store project then? It isn't recognising the namespace.

Comment: Every project is a separate unit and normally can see only its own contents (classes, modules, resources etc.). If you want to access classes from another project, you must include a reference of that project into calling project. Right-click your calling project and choose **Add Reference** and then select the target project from the list of projects (Solution tab).

Comment: If you need code that its shared between the two, you need to create a new `Class library` project and add it to your solution, then add your cs file containing the class to that project, then `Add a reference` to that project from both projects using it

Comment: As usual, there is a whole lot of detail associated with this specific task, but I'm trying to keep it simple for you. This is only the tip of the iceberg. If you happen to continue, you'll see what I mean.

Comment: @dotNET When I go to add the reference it tells me: "Unable to add reference to project UniApp.WindowsPhone"

Comment: mmm... I cannot see what projects you have in your solution and what platforms are they targeting. There could be many reasons for the error message you've posted. For one, I'd suggest you should check the target .net framework of both the caller and callee projects.

Comment: I've added the image of my solution layout.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at the Visual Studio documentation about solutions, projects, folders and references. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b142f8e7.aspx) and [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez524kew.aspx) (including the subitems on each).

Comment: Seeing your edit, you *already* have a `UniApp1.Shared` project, which, by the name, is probably referenced by the other two projects. Why not add `print.cs` there?

Comment: @Jcl Because, it would seem, I'm an idiot haha. Thanks for your help guys; I've got it sorted now. :)

Answer (score 4):

Classes in a c# project live in ***namespaces***, not on ***folders***. Whether the folder name matches the namespace name is completely optional.

Generally, on top of your class name, you'll have a `namespace blablabla {` clause. To use the class in that namespace, you either do

1) On top of the file using that class: `using blablabla;` and then just access using the classname where you want.

-or-

2) Directly specifying the **whole** namespace name: `blablabla.ClassName`.

More info about namespaces on [the official MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0d941h9d.aspx)

Comment: Now that I see your edit, you need to make sure you add it to the `project` and not to the `solution`

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem, which could actually be the same issue.

If I have a project in folder "Sample" with my .sln .csproj and .cs code, then decide to add a sub-folder called "Sample\Tests" and try to add files from the Tests files I have various problems.

If I drag those files or use Add Existing to project, Visual Studio 2015 makes copies of the files in the Tests sub-folder into the Sample folder then adds those to the project.

If I decide to add the files from the Tests sub-folder into the solution, then I can see the folder in the solution but I am not able to use the classes in Tests from the code within "Sample".

The only way around this I have found is to create a new Shared Project and include the Tests project, then I can use the classes from the Tests folder.

The namespace makes no difference, as it doesn't solve the problem when trying to add source code from other folders, and it seems VS expects a project before code can be used from other folders.

Unless anyone knows away around this?